# ReactNativeJS: C++ Exception in 'nativeRequireModuleConfig'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a fully function react native app for iOS. I tried making android version as well. When i tried to run it on simulator it throw the following error :

```
E/ReactNativeJS: C++ Exception in 'nativeRequireModuleConfig': java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

Gradle console :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)\n\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)\n","tool":"Dex"}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 19.746 secs
```

I'm using following modules in my project :
[image]

Any solutions please?

---

UPDATE:

Logcat from Real Device :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
                                                                Process: com.opencampus, PID: 10821
                                                                java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/data/com.opencampus/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-gcm-8.1.0_4d535f5b5c1f36628a96d503891e7dd5c3b4eb8f-classes.dex)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdo(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceModule.getConstants(RNDeviceModule.java:83)
                                                                    at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.getConstants(JavaModuleWrapper.java:130)
                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: How are you building? Are you using `react-native run-android` or the `./gradlew` script? And what version of react-native?

Comment: I'm using run-android. it's RN 38